# Getting Out of memory due to large JSON data

Tags: android, json, large-data

I'm making an `Android` app. In that `Web service` sends a `JSON object` and app parses the object and displays on the screen. In one case, `JSON object` is too big and I get `Out of Memory exception`. My solution is to get that `JSON object` and embed it in the app code, so that it wouldn't need to get that `JSON object` from the server. Can you tell any other things that I can do for this problem? Or can you tell me how to get that `JSON object` from Web service?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you fetching any photo?

Comment: No. Its a plain huge text json.

Comment: Can you show code snippet where you are getting exception? Stacktrace of exception as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the large size data from server to mobile. JSON is light weight. If you want to pass the data using more efficient way then passes it in pagination. If you want to use more lighter protocol than JSON then implement the below google protocol which are really useful, which are supporting major languages. Below are smaller Serialised data structure. Google's data interchange protocol.

[1.Google Protocol](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

[2.Flat Buffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/)

[3.Nano-proto buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/javanano)

Hope this will be useful you.

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error comes when available heap size is full, you have to clear cache programmatically. Also use jackson for parsing json data. may be you are initializing multiple arrays for storing data.

Comment: Agreed! It can be reason for getting this exception.
But what is the advantage of using jackson JSON parsing instead of simple JSON parsing.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android

Comment: please have a look at above link you will get idea.